# Getting error in android Kernel compilation

Tags: android, kernel

I am new to android. i am try to compile android kernel 3.4.0 for HTC device.

After running cross compile command,

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/home/jharvard/ndk-x86/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
```

when I run make clean command

```
make clean && make mrproper
```

It shows errors,

```
/home/jharvard/kernel-code/linux/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: arm-eabi-gcc: command not found
/home/jharvard/kernel-code/linux/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: arm-eabi-gcc: command not found
```

I am not getting any clue to solve this error. Suggest me how to get rid of this error. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

actually the kernel 3.4 requires toolchain version 4.7 for correct compilation. Download the ndk from here developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html and then point to newly downloaded toolchain with command: CROSS_COMPILE=(your_download_location)/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
And its done.